# ViewController.h and ViewController.m are not created automatically

Tags: xcode, macos, visual-studio, header-files

I am studying by self for application development.
OS: MacOS
Software: Visual Studio(8.10.11 - build 8) for coding
Xcode(13.1)

I am referring a help article below published by Microsoft since I am using Visual Studio.

Ref; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/get-started/hello-mac

However, I am sticking at Outlets/Actions section.
I open storyboard on Xcode, and tried to sync between UI change to ViewController.h file.
I recognized that I do not have .h nor even .m file.

Did I have to create ViewController.h file manually??

There was also a sentence like this below.

> This stub .h file mirrors the ViewController.designer.cs that is automatically added to a Xamarin.Mac project when a new NSWindow is created. This file will be used to synchronize the changes made by Interface Builder and is where the Outlets and Actions are created so that UI elements are exposed to C# code.

I researched NSWindow but I am super newbie on App Dev. So I am about to lose my mind and wasting my time for a long (T_T)

Could someone help me here?
This Visual Studio ver will not create .h/.m file anymore?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry for this dumb question.
I still do not have any header file nor m file.

However, when I double clicked storyboard, I saw header and m file.
I used to open storyboard file on Xcode because I did not have an option to open from Visual Studio even though I right-clicked storyboard file like "open -> Xcode interface builder" stuff.

Anyway, the issue was resolved.
Case closed.